# How to call a function only after the previous function is fully executed in java

Tags: java, android

I have a view class which has two methods lets say func1 and func2. In func1 there is a timer of 4 secs. Now when I am accessing these methods in an activity I want to call func2 only after 4secs in func1 gets completed.

Now when I am accessing these in an activity how do I make sure func2 is called only after func1 fully executed. Thanks.

Comment: Please explain in what situations you want to call func1 and func2.

Comment: If func2 is called when func1 not completed, what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 2):

If `fun2()` should be always executed after timer in `fun1()` is finished, then simply call it inside `onFinsih()` method as follows:

```
 public void func1(){
     new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
          func2();
        }
    }.start();


}

public void func2(){

}
```

The reason this is good place to call function is, `onFinish` callback will be fired when the time is up. This will ensure that your intended behavior is achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Would there be anything wrong in calling `func2()` after the `CountDownTimer` has finished:

```
@Override
public void onFinish() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    func2();
}
```

Actually, this is the only logical place where calling `func2()` makes sense, because you don't know that the countdown is finished until `onFinish()` gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
public void onFinish() {
    func2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, JRE executes instructions specified in each line sequentially. Here, I see that you have a special requirement because of **multi-threading**.

Following approaches can be used to tackle this problem:

**Option 1:**

Call func2() inside onFinish() method which is part of func1(). So that you're sure it is executing after func1() code execution.

```
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
      func2();
    }
```

**Option 2:**

Since you're setting up the wait time in func1() method, add timer before calling func2() in your calling module.

```
func1();
setTimeout(function () {
    func2();
}, 5000);
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You can call fun2() in your `func1()` CountDownTimer method in `onFinish()`.

***Like :***

```
    public void func1(){
     new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                     func2();
                }
            }.start();
    }

public void func2(){

}
```